# SILVERLIGHT. How to download file like from web-site

Tags: silverlight, file

I want download file from server. I know how to do this using WCF/RIA services. How can I do this like in web site. For example: I click button and It will appear standard dialog browser window to download file.

Answer (score 1):

Use the Hyperlink control and link it to a server-side URL.  This is what I've done in my app to avoid the whole generic save file prompt restrictions of the default SL sandbox.

Comment: Do I need write custom http handler?

Comment: something like this? http://aspnet-cookbook.info/O.Reilly-ASP.NET.Cookbook.Second.Edition/0596100647/aspnetckbk2-CHP-20-SECT-3.html ?